# Как сравнить элементы с одинаковыми индексами в set C++

Tags: c++, структуры-данных

У меня есть два сета и мне нужно сравнивать элемент из сета1 с элементом из сета 2 с одинаковыми индексами. Как это можно реализовать? Ниже приведен пример для массивов.

```
for (int i = 0; i < min(a1.size(), a2.size()); i++)
  if (a1[i] == a2[i])
    // код
```

Comment: У множества нет индексов, оно не упорядочено. Для работы со множествами имеет смысл использовать операции над множествами, например, [`std::set_difference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference) или [`std::set_intersection`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection).

Comment: set или vector?

Comment: Ну просто идите итераторами...

Comment: Пытался сделать итераторами, но нужно ведь обращаться с тем же итератором и к другому сету. А итератор ссылается на мемори-адрес конкретной ячейки сета, то есть невозможно этим же итератором взять элемент другого сета.

Comment: @Trounee, инкрементируйте сразу два итератора

Comment: так set или vector? какой тип у a1/a2?

Comment: @KoVadim, для вектора код из примера отработал бы. Думаю речь о set

Comment: как бы у set нет `operator[]`

Comment: О том и речь, что у сета нет оператора [], иначе я бы сделал так как в примере и ничего не спрашивал. Пример для представления того, что я хочу получить, и он работает для vector, а не для set.

Comment: @Trounee у сета и индексов нет, но спрашиваете же.

Comment: @Trounee так как у set нет индексов, то и нельзя сравнить элементы, которые находятся под одинаковыми индексами (нет ножек - нет варенья). Рассказывайте оригинальную задачу.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по всему, вы хотите совпадающие элементы множеств. Если так, вам нужно использовать [`std::intersection`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection). Пример:

```
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

#include <iostream>
```

```
std::set<int> s1 { 1, 2, 3, 5, 7 };
std::set<int> s2 { 0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };

std::set<int> diff;
std::set_intersection(begin(s1), end(s1), begin(s2), end(s2),
                      std::inserter(diff, begin(diff)));

for (auto v : diff)
    std::cout << v << " "; // 1 3 5 7
```

Answer (score 0):

> Ну просто идите итераторами...
>   (c) Harry

```
std::set<int> first;
std::set<int> second;

for(auto firstIt = first.begin(), secondIt = second.begin(); firstIt != first.end() && secondIt != second.end(); ++firstIt, ++secondIt){
    if(*firstIt == *secondIt)
        //код
}
```

То же самое в столбик:

```
std::set<int> first;
auto firstBegin = first.begin();
auto firstEnd = first.end();

std::set<int> second;
auto secondBegin = second.begin();
auto secondEnd = second.end();

while(firstBegin != firstEnd && secondBegin != secondEnd){
    if(*firstBegin == *secondBegin){
        //код
    }

    ++firstBegin;
    ++secondBegin;
}
```

Я склоняюсь ко второму варианту, так как он умещается в мой монитор

Answer (score 0):

если хотите наглядно увидить совпадающие элементы, то предлогаю

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

using std::set;
using std::cout;

int main()
{    
    int m1[] = {1, 3, 5, 6, 7},  m2[] = { 2, 3, 5, 7, 9 };
    set<int> s1, s2;
    s1.insert(m1, &m1[5]);
    s2.insert(m2, &m2[5]);
    std::transform(s1.begin(), s1.end(), s2.begin(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "),
                                         [](int i, int j) { return i == j;});
    return 0;
}
```

выдаст 0 1 1 0 0,  т. е. для совпадающих пар  true

Comment: а если хотите  сохранить информацию о совпадении пар, то вместо ostream_iterator  применяйте back_inserter(v), где v  это vector<bool> обьявленный заранее.